# Should there be a reputation requirement for voting on closed questions?

Tags: feature-request, reputation, closed-questions, voting

Should there be a higher reputation requirement to vote on questions that are already closed?

This would be to prevent kicking "misguided" users into the ground with downvotes
(and also to prevent the +10 from the occasional pity vote which can result in a positive reputation balance on a negative question).

Answer (score 1):

No.

You are suggesting a different voting scale for open vs closed questions. That only adds complexity and confusion. People are free to use their votes as they see fit once they reach 15 rep for up votes and 100 for down votes for open or closed questions.